# What's the difference between utf8_unicode_ci and utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

Tags: mysql, unicode

What is the difference between `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` and `utf8_unicode_ci` database text coding in mysql (especially in terms of performance) ?

Update:

There are similar differences between utf8mb4_unicode_ci and utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci?

Comment: These are collations, governing how sorting of data occurs. `mbX` means multi-byte (stores one character in X bytes), `0900` is the collation algorithm, `ai` means accent insensitive, `ci` means case insensitive

Answer (score 84, accepted):

- The *encoding* is the same.  That is, the bytes look the same.
- The *character set* is different.  utf8mb4 has more characters.
- The *collation* (how comparisions are done) is different.
- The *perfomance* is different, but it rarely matters.

`utf8_unicode_ci` implies the `CHARACTER SET utf8`, which includes only the 1-, 2-, and 3-byte UTF-8 characters.  Hence it excludes most Emoji and some Chinese characters.

`utf8mb4_unicode_ci` implies the `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` is the corresponding `COLLATION` for the 4-byte `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.

The Unicode organization has been evolving the specification over the years.  Here are the mappings from its "versions" to MySQL Collations:

```
4.0   _unicode_
5.2.0 _unicode_520_ (Unicode 2009; MySQL GA 5.6 2013)
9.0   _0900_
14.0  _uca1400_ai_ci etc.  as/ai and cs/ci (MariaDB-10.10, not MySQL)
```

Most of the differences will be in areas that most people never encounter.  One example:  At some point, a change allowed Emoji to be distinguished and ordered in some manner.

The suffix ([MySQL doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-collation-names.html)):

```
_bin      -- just compare the bits; don't consider case folding, accents, etc
_ci       -- explicitly case insensitive (A=a) and implicitly accent insensitive (a=á)
_ai_ci    -- explicitly case insensitive and accent insensitive
_as (etc) -- accent-sensitive (etc)
```

Performance:

```
_bin         -- simple, fast
_general_ci  -- fails to compare multiple letters; eg ss=ß, so somewhat fast
...          -- slower
_900_        -- (8.0) much faster because of a rewrite
```

However:  The speed of collation is usually the least of the performance issues in queries.  `INDEXes`, `JOINs`, subqueries, table scans, etc are much more critical to performance.

Comment: there are similar differences between `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` ?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski - Yes.

Comment: what is the largest byte size character in the `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` collation?

Comment: @BugWhisperer - The largest _character_ for "utf8mb4" is 4 bytes.  This applies to  all utf8mb4 _collations_ ("utf8mb4_*, including that one).

Comment: Awesome answer! Where did you get the data about performance from?

Comment: @Stalinko - From OracleOpenWorld.  A developer pointed out that 8.0 has a big rewrite of the collation code and pointed out that it is much faster.  (I have not yet devised a realistic test case to verify or quantify the speedup.)

Comment: Thanks @RickJames, after your comment I think I'll try to convert my 100gb DB into this new collation to see if it gives me some boost.

Comment: @Stalinko - Measure the timings before and after the conversion.  And let us know.

Comment: Cool, but, which of them should I use? Which of them is "most updated" or better, with more support?

Comment: @giovannipds - For 8.0, simply use the default charset and collation.  If you are working only with a particular language, pick a collation specific to that language.  _0900_ is generic; many languages are not "perfectly" sorted by it.  Spanish, in particular, has two collations; one treats "ch" as a letter that sorts between "cz" and "d":  http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8mb4_collations.html

Comment: @giovannipds - As for support, I would pick 8.0.  As for "updated", I don't expect any updates; MySQL got burned when it "fixed" the german "ss" collation:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#german_sharp_s_

Comment: @RickJames I update main question with my comment-question because I think I it is connected and also useful - If you want you can also update your answer

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski - I'm ahead of you.  My short list with 4.0, 5.20, and 9.0 addresses your Comment.